# Selected row 'spontaneously' resets to default values in FetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, swift, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have a `TableViewController` class that implements `UITableViewController` and `NSFetchedResultsController` protocols.

On selecting a `row`, the app is designed to segue to a detail screen. However, when I first select any `row` other than the first, the data in the `cell` changes to show the default values as defined in the *storyboard*.

As far as I can determine, there is no code in my app that does this. And when I step through the code in debug mode, I am unable to discover any code that is triggered when the `row` is selected.

Consequently, I am unsure what parts of my app's code to include to help identify what might be going on.

Any suggestions on where I go from here would be much valued.

EDIT ----

I've been asked to post my code. As I have no idea which code is triggering, here's the class definition for the TVC which implements the *UITableViewController* and *NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate* protocol. I've only included the overall class definition, class properties and two methods *initializeFetchedResultsController* and *ConfigureCell*.

I don't know if this limited code sample is going to be enough as I am unable to determine what is being called when the user touches the row at runtime.

I'm happy to include more if there are any ideas.

```
class PlayerTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {

var players: [NSManagedObject] = []

var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>!

var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.managedObjectContext

func initializeFetchedResultsController() {
    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return
    }

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Golfer")
    let firstNameSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "firstName", ascending: true)
    let lastNameSort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "lastName", ascending: true)
    request.sortDescriptors = [firstNameSort, lastNameSort]

    let moc = appDelegate.managedObjectContext
    fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: moc, sectionNameKeyPath: "firstName", cacheName: nil)
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

    do {
        try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        fatalError("Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
    }
}

func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var handicap: Float

    let cellIdentifier = "PlayerTableViewCell"

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath as IndexPath) as? PlayerTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of PlayerTableViewCell")
        }

    // Populate cell from the NSManagedObject instance
    guard let player = fetchedResultsController.object(at: indexPath as IndexPath) as? Golfer else {
        fatalError("Unexpected Object in FetchedResultsController")
    }

    let firstName = player.value(forKey: "firstName") as! String?
    let lastName = player.value(forKey: "lastName") as! String?
    let fullName = firstName! + " " + lastName!
    handicap = player.value(forKey: "exactHandicap") as! Float

    cell.playerFullName?.text = fullName

    cell.playerPhoto.image = UIImage(data: player.value(forKey: "photo") as! Data)

    cell.numExactHandicap.text = "\(Int(handicap))"
    cell.numStrokesReceived.text = "\(handicap.cleanValue)"
}
```

}

Comment: You'll need to share data whenever row is selected?

Comment: @Dave  Can you paste your code?

Comment: @bibscy - not sure if you're asking me to share whole app so have included some code which may assist. Key point is that the behaviour I see happens when a row in the table is selected, yet I cannot trap any event at that point nor see what code is running.